# Programmatically add a FilteredTextBoxExtender within a composite control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm currently trying to add a FilteredTextBoxExtender in a ASP.NET composite control, but I can't get it to work.

I have the following code within the overridden CreateChildControls method:

```
var textbox = new TextBox { ID = string.Format("{0}_textbox", ID);
var filteredTextBoxExtender = new FilteredTextBoxExtender { ID = string.Format("{0}_filter", ID), TargetControlID = textbox.ID, FilterType = FilterTypes.Numbers };

Controls.Add(textbox);
Controls.Add(filteredTextBoxExtender);
```

Somehow, it looks like it is added correctly when I view the source of my test page, but it won't fire the filtering

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.FilteredTextBoxBehavior, {"FilterType":2,"id":"ctl00_testTextBox_testTextBox_filter"}, null, null, $get("ctl00_testTextBox_testTextBox_textBox"));
});

...

<input id="ctl00_testTextBox" name="ctl00$testTextBox$testTextBox_textBox" type="text" value="" id="ctl00_testTextBox_testTextBox_textBox" />
```

Any idea what goes on here, and how to get it to fire the filtering?

edit:
I've narrowed it down to a matter of dynamically choosing which controls to render. The FilteredTextBoxExtender works if I explicitely render each child control, but not if I don't render one of the child controls in the composite control (a label control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The problem is the textbox's id. If you check the generated JavaScript, you can sense, the input id is different from assigned id to `$get("ctl00_testTextBox_testTextBox_textBox")`. So your code doesn't work. <s>You should mark your composite control by INamingContainer marker inerface. Thus, the composite control's id combines with the added textbox id and generates an unique identity. It resolves the problem.</s>

```
public class Foo : CompositeControl
{

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        var textbox = new TextBox { ID = "textbox" }
        var filteredTextBoxExtender = new FilteredTextBoxExtender { TargetControlID = textbox.ID, FilterType = FilterTypes.Numbers };

        Controls.Add(textbox);
        Controls.Add(filteredTextBoxExtender);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but INamingContainer is redundant because my control already inherits from CompositeControl.

I've edited my question with some more information that I have discovered since the post

Comment: Yea, the `CompositeControl` has already implemented `INamingContainer`. I'm going to edit my post. However, I can't realize the updated part of your question.

Comment: Can't remember what the problem was here so I'm just going to close it. Thanks for the help anyway